# Mixed partial derivatives with respect to n variables

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

I have the following generic set of variables:

```
x = {x1, x2, ..., xn}
nu = {0, 1, 2, ..., n - 1}
order(nu) := Total @ nu;
```

I would like to calculate:

$$ \frac{\partial^{\operatorname{order}(v)}}{\partial_1^{\nu_1} \partial_2^{\nu_2} \dots \partial_n^{\nu_n}} $$

With a generic $x$. Indeed, I would like a function of this sort:

```
MyMixedDerivative[f,x_?VectorQ]:= ...
```

Suggestions?

Comment: You might need `Derivative`.

Comment: I tried this: but it does not seam to work out: 
testx = {x1, x2, x3};
testf[x1_, x2_, x3_] := x1^3 x2^2 x3^2
Derivative[Table[1, {i, 1, 3}]][testf[x1, x2, x3]]

Comment: How about `Derivative[Sequence @@ Table[1, {i, 1, 3}]][testf][Sequence @@ testx]`?

Comment: It doesn't perform the derivative. I really can't figure out why.

Comment: It does. See my new comment.

Comment: Great, please write an answe so that I may accept it to keep trace. This was not at all straight forward to me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK. If one looks at the documentation of [`Derivative`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Derivative.html), it should be found that `Derivative` accepts two arguments. The first is a `Sequence` of orders of derivatives to be taken and the second is a `Function` or a `Symbol` representing a function, say `f`. So when the order argument is passed to `Derivative`, it should be destructured from a `List` to a `Sequence`:

```
testx = {x1, x2, x3}; testf[x1_, x2_, x3_] := x1^3 x2^2 x3^2;
Derivative[Sequence @@ Table[1, {i, 1, 3}]][testf][Sequence @@ testx]
```

which gives

> 12 x1^2 x2 x3

Moreover, if one digs deeper in the "Details" part of the documentation, s/he should find out that the above description of requirement is not quite accurate. The true requirement is to achieve a structure consistency between the order argument and the argument of `f`. So below codes work as well

```
testf2[{x1_, x2_, x3_}] := x1^3 x2^2 x3^2;
Derivative[Table[1, {i, 1, 3}]][testf2][testx]

testf3[{x1_, x2_}, x3_] := x1^3 x2^2 x3^2;
Derivative[{1, 1}, 1][testf3][{x1, x2}, x3]
```

and other combinations of `Sequence` and `List` as the argument.

Comment: The second part of your comment is inspiring. Thank you a lot.

Comment: @MirkoAveta You are welcome. Actually, it is a new point to me, too :)

Comment: In short, `Derivative[]` is supposed to inherit the argument structure of the function it is operating on. To give yet another example: `Derivative[{1, 0}, {0}, 0][HypergeometricPFQ][{-2, 1/2}, {1}, 1/2]` is equivalent to `Derivative[1, 0, 0, 0][Hypergeometric2F1][-2, 1/2, 1, 1/2]`, since `HypergeometricPFQ[{a, b}, {c}, x] == Hypergeometric2F1[a, b, c, x]`.

Comment: @J.M.isaway Thx for your comments. Yes, "to inherit" is an accurate and concise description.